# Concise form of using value from a file or default

Tags: bash

I have a value in file `bar.txt`; let's say it contains the text `bar`. I want to combine the file contents with a string prefix such as `"foo"` and store in the variable `foobarValue`. If the file does not exist, I want to set `foobarValue` to the string `"missing"`.

I can do something like this:

```bash
barFile=bar.txt
foobarValue="missing"
if [[ -f $barFile ]]; then
  foobarValue="foo$(< $barFile)"
fi
```

I can shorten this using short-circuiting logic:

```bash
barFile=bar.txt
foobarValue="missing"
[[ -f $barFile ]] && foobarValue="foo$(< $barFile)"
```

This still has the awkward default value initialization `foobarValue="missing"` at the beginning. Is there any way to make this even more concise and assign a default value to `foobarValue` if `$barFile` does not exist?

(Note that in my particular case, the default value I want is not `"missing"` but instead an empty string `""`, so if there's a special-case answer for that, I'd be interested to know it. In this case if I leave out `foobarValue=""`, I get an "unbound variable" error, so I decided to ask the question in terms of some general default value.)

Comment: One possibility is `foobarValue=foo$(cat -- "$barFile" 2>/dev/null || echo missing)`.  That will behave differently from your code when the file exists but is not readable though.